# Loop through GetType().GetProperties() and bind each property with asp-for (Razor Pages)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I just found out that GetType().GetProperties() even exists, is it possible to use this way?

The goal is to use a loop to get all properties on a specific entity without having to hardcode every property inside the HTML, update every edited property and save the new info in an OnPost with the help of the [BindProperty] annotation.
I'm unable to correctly bind with the asp-for taghelper.

```
    <form method="post">

       @foreach (var prop in Model.Product.GetType().GetProperties())
       {
           <label asp-for="@prop.Name"></label>
           <input asp-for="@prop.GetValue(Model.Product)" class="form-control" />
       }
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

    </form>
```

Running this code gives me the following exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

If I use value="@prop.GetValue(Model.Product)" inside the  tag I correctly get the information when loading the edit page. But when submitting the form I don't get the new values previously entered.

Here's the model from the modelpage

```
[BindProperty]
public ProductModel? Product { get; set; }

OnGet()
{
   Product = db.GetProduct(id);
}
```

Thanks for taking your time reading this!

Comment: Thank you for the reminder and your provided answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tag Helper` helps us to write code in a style of **declarative programming**. When you find it difficult to render different fields dynamically by reflection, try to use the `Html helper` as an alternative way.

If you just want to render the input without value set. `Html Helper` works fine. But it seems you also want to set value for inputs, I try the following way but it does not make sense in asp.net core 3.x:

```
@Html.Editor(prop.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@Value=prop.GetValue(Model.Product)} })
```

So I suggest you could customize a tag helper which sets id , name and value of input from the `asp-for-model` attribute and `asp-for-prop` attribute in the view.

ConditionTagHelper:

```
namespace AuthoringTagHelpers.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for-prop")]

    public class ConditionTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for-prop")]
        public ModelExpression Property { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for-model")]
        public ModelExpression Model { get; set; }


        public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var propName = Property.ModelExplorer.Model.ToString();
            var modelName = Model.Name.ToString();
            var modelExProp = Model.ModelExplorer.Properties.Single(x => x.Metadata.PropertyName.Equals(propName));
            var propValue = modelExProp.Model;

            var para = modelName + "." + propName;

            output.Attributes.Add("id", para);
            output.Attributes.Add("name", para);
            output.Attributes.Add("value", propValue);

            base.Process(context, output);
        }
    }
}
```

In the _viewImports.cshtml, :

```
@addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers   //AuthoringTagHelpers depends on your project name
```

**Note**:  The first string after `@addTagHelper` specifies the tag helper to load (Use "*" for all tag helpers), and the second string `AuthoringTagHelpers` specifies the assembly the tag helper is in.

Page:

```
<form method="post">

    @foreach (var prop in Model.Product.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        @Html.Label(prop.Name)
        <input asp-for-model="@Model.Product" asp-for-prop="@prop.Name" class="form-control" />
    }
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Hello Rena! Thank you for very much for your reply. I solved it by doing a custom ViewModel (class) and filling a list of ViewModelClass with GetType().GetProperties() inside the OnGet. 

I did a quick attempt at your method but couldn't get it to work, it didn't seem to bind the list, when I get to OnPost the list is empty again. But it did provide me insight into creating custom tag-helpers, thank you!

Comment: use this name :`@Html.Label($"{nameof(Model.InputModel)}.{prop.Name}")
            @Html.Editor($"{nameof(Model.InputModel)}.{prop.Name}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@Value=prop.GetValue(Model.InputModel)} })`